# Stopping a repeating alarm from a BroadcastReceiver - is it possible?

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I have an `AlarmManager` that sets a repeating alarm for the purpose of periodically querying a server.

```
    private AlarmManager alarmManager; 
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);

    //startService(photosIntent);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),0,photosIntent,0);


    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
            10000, pendingIntent);
```

And I start an IntentService within the AlarmReceiver's `onReceive()` method. AlarmReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver. Here is the `onReceive()` method:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Intent photosIntent = new Intent(context,JSONPhotosParser.class);
            context.startService(photosIntent);

}
```

Now, this is something crazy I want to do, as it is not very practical. Is there any way I can stop my `AlarmManager` from within the `BroadcastReceiver`. I can also think of a practical scenario where such an action would be required. Say I am querying the status of a network connection using `ConnectivityManager` and if a connection exists I would start an `IntentService` that queries a server (which is my current scenario). If network status returns false, I would like to stop the repeating alarm set by the `AlarmManager`.

Is this possible within the BroadcastReceiver ? I understand that an AlarmManager can be removed using `cancel(PendingIntent operation)`. But how do I create PendingIntent inside the BroadcastReceiver ?

Any help on this would be most appreciated. From an Android noob.

Answer (score 0):

refer this link :

AlarmManager.cancel (PendingIntent operation)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29